# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError when running Logstash plugin

Tags: java, ruby, logstash, jruby

I have a java program which converts data into JSON format.
I am able to successfully build the program into a jar file, and successfully use the jar's functionality in a stand-alone program.

I've created a jruby plugin for Logstash which calls this jar.
When running Logstash:

```
gem build logstash-filter-example.gemspec &&
../../logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-filter-example-0.1.1.gem &&
../../logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/bin/logstash -e 'input { stdin{} } filter { example {} } output {stdout { codec => rubydebug }}'
```

I receive the following error:

```
/dataservice/DataServiceClient.java:156:in `parseQueryRowEntry': java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.JsonNodeFactory.numberNode(Ljava/math/BigDecimal;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/NumericNode;
    from com/mike/dataservice/DataServiceClient.java:93:in `toJsonObject'
    from com/mike/dataservice/DataServiceClient.java:66:in `getData'
    from java/lang/reflect/Method.java:498:in `invoke'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/vendor/local_gems/ecdbfdf7/logstash-filter-example-0.1.1/lib/logstash/filters/example.rb:49:in `filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:145:in `do_filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:164:in `multi_filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:164:in `multi_filter'
    from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:161:in `multi_filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filters/base.rb:161:in `multi_filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filter_delegator.rb:46:in `multi_filter'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/filter_delegator.rb:46:in `multi_filter'
    from (eval):42:in `filter_func'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:398:in `filter_batch'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:398:in `filter_batch'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:379:in `worker_loop'
    from /Users/michael.dobrin/compilationsFromSource/logstash-5.6.7/logstash-5.6.7.freshinstall/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:342:in `start_workers'
    from java/lang/Thread.java:748:in `run'
```

For some reason, the numberNode() method is not recognized.
However, I have no problem when running my jar with a standalone jruby program, even when using Logstash's locally installed instance of jruby.  Furthermore, the program successfully uses some methods from my jar file... numberNode(Ljava/math/BigDecimal;) is the only method not recognized. Why can't Logstash see this?

Comment: I've looked into this more. Logstash internally uses jackson-databind v 2.9.1 which was different than my version as defined in my gradle file. When I set the versions to be equal, the error disappeared.

Does Logstash look at it's own .jar files when running my plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely Logstash adds `JsonNodeFactory` to classpath which is incompatible with the version that your application expects. The method was refactored around *jackson-databind-2.10*.

You can verify it by checking where the class is being loaded from. E.g.
`System.out.println(JsonNodeFactory.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());`

Comment: How exactly does Logstash add to the classpath? Is this done in the settings file?

Comment: Check the *${LOGSTASH_HOME}/bin/logstash* file and you can see that all *jar* files from *${LOGSTASH_HOME}/logstash-core/lib/jars* are appended to classpath. If for some reason you do not want to use the same version of that dependancy you should look into Gradle Shading - perhaps https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow.

Comment: I'm using Logstash 5.6.7 - is this done elsewhere for earlier versions?

Comment: As far as I understand the .jar files for Logstash itself are defined in *../logstash-core/lib/logstash-core_jars.rb* which was generated when Logstash was built. However the dependencies for Ruby gems should end up in *../vendor/jruby/lib/..* after the plugin is installed.

Comment: I'm still not clear exactly on the difference between ".jar files for Logstash itself" and "dependencies for Ruby gems."  I thought Logstash was built on Ruby, so shouldn't all .jar files be dependencies for the Ruby gems used by Logstash?

Comment: I've got it now.
../vendor/jruby/lib/.. is for the plugin ruby gem itself. Adding my jars here seems to work!